# Skew is not changing javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a javascript slider function in which I made a div and skewed it on hover.
 Now I just want that on click this skew must be 0 degree and i also want to reset csss value on mouse out function.

Lines of Javascript functions are as foolows:-

```
        $("#leftHalf").animate ({"transform": "skew(0deg)"});
```

and my CSS ia as Follows:-

```
           #leftHalf {
           background: url(../images/banner.jpg);
           width: 100%;
           left: 0px;
           height: 100%;
           -ms-transform: skew(65deg); /* IE 9*/ 
           -webkit-transform: skew(65deg);/* Chrome, Safari, Opera*/ 
           transform: skew(65deg);
           background-size:120%;
           background-repeat:no-repeat;
           }
```

Can Anybody tell me why my skew is not changing.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I dont think there's animation for skew by default in jquery. But there's a little plugin. Check this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zhMyg/1/)** you can get the `.js` file from fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

From jQuery api documentation (https://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height,
>   or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the
>   jQuery.Color() plugin is used). Property values are treated as a
>   number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be
>   specified where applicable.

so you can't animate "skew(0deg)", but you can change style of element, and use css3 animations to perform smooth change:

```
$("#leftHalf").css ({
  "transform": "skew(0deg)",
  "-webkit-transform" : "skew(0deg)", 
  "-ms-transform":"skew(0deg)"
 });
```

add to css:

```
#leftHalf {
...
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
-ms-transition: -ms-transform .5s;
transition: transform .5s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i want this id(#leftHalf) to show on hover of an attribute and and when click on same attribute i want to skew it from its angle now i.e. 65 deg to 0 deg....can you give me your mail id i am gonna show you the actual problem....and maybe you can help me there and i will mark your answer....@Bille